# DropdownLists in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to use a DropdownlistFor in MVC to add an object to my database.  I am able to populate the dropdown fine, but when I post the form I get an error as the ID of the dropdown (which is a foreign key to the Team object) is populated but not the actual value.  Here is my code :

```
    [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult FixtureAdd()
        {
            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> teams = _repository.GetTeams()
              .Select(c => new SelectListItem
              {
                  Value = c.TeamId.ToString(),
                  Text = c.TeamName
              }).ToList();

            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> weeks = _repository.GetWeeks()
              .Select(c => new SelectListItem
              {
                  Value = c.ToString(),
                  Text = c.ToString()
              }).ToList();

            ViewBag.Teams = new SelectList(teams, "Value", "Text");
            ViewBag.Weeks = new SelectList(weeks, "Value", "Text");

            string apiUri = Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { controller = "fixture", });
            ViewBag.ApiUrl = new Uri(Request.Url, apiUri).AbsoluteUri.ToString();

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult FixtureAdd(Fixture fx)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                     //TODO: Add insert logic here
                    _repository.AddFixture(fx);
                    return RedirectToAction("FixtureAdd");
                }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
                {
                    foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                    {
                        foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                        {
                            Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                        }
                    }

                    return View(fx);
                }   
            }
            else
            {
                IEnumerable<SelectListItem> teams = _repository.GetTeams()
                  .Select(c => new SelectListItem
                  {
                      Value = c.TeamId.ToString(),
                      Text = c.TeamName
                  }).ToList();

                ViewBag.Teams = new SelectList(teams, "Value", "Text");

                IEnumerable<SelectListItem> weeks = _repository.GetWeeks()
                  .Select(c => new SelectListItem
                  {
                      Value = c.ToString(),
                      Text = c.ToString()
                  }).ToList();

                ViewBag.Weeks = new SelectList(teams, "Value", "Text");

                return View(fx);
            }
        }

    public IEnumerable<Team> GetTeams()
        {
            return _db.Teams.ToArray();
        }

public partial class Fixture
    {
        public int FixtureId { get; set; }
        public string Season { get; set; }
        public byte Week { get; set; }

        //foreign key
        public int AwayTeamId { get; set; }
        //navigation properties
        public virtual Team AwayTeam { get; set; }

        //foreign key
        public int HomeTeamId { get; set; }
        //navigation properties
        public virtual Team HomeTeam { get; set; }

        public byte? AwayTeamScore { get; set; }
        public byte? HomeTeamScore { get; set; }
    }

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fixture</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Season)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Season)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Season)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Week)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Week, (SelectList)ViewBag.Weeks)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AwayTeam.TeamId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AwayTeam.TeamId, (SelectList)ViewBag.Teams)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AwayTeam.TeamId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AwayTeamScore)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AwayTeamScore)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AwayTeamScore)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HomeTeam.TeamId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.HomeTeam.TeamId, (SelectList)ViewBag.Teams)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HomeTeam.TeamId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HomeTeamScore)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HomeTeamScore)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HomeTeamScore)
        </div>

        <p>
            <button data-bind='click: save'>Add fixture</button>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

The TeamId foreign key field gets populated in the post but the TeamName does not.  Any ideas why?  This is my first attempt at this so I expect I am possibly making more than one error with this.

Comment: MVC isn't like ASP where listing objects in a drop-down and selecting the key is actually assigning the object. You will need to re-fetch the object you desire after the key has been populated in the submission.

Comment: So I need to make a call to a method for example GetTeamNameByTeamId on the post to fetch the object again?

Comment: In your submit action you need to re-fetch the object you're based on the ID that was submitted in the model. I'll see if I can post what I'm talking about as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC, unlike traditional ASP, is light-weight and doesn't store all those objects in a hidden field. That is to say, if you had the following:

```
class Customer {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

In normal ASP you could map a collection of these objects to a dropdown list and on the post back you'd get the original object that was referenced in the result. MVC doesn't work this way because it's not storing these objects any more. So if you want that intended object you're going to need to use the passed ID and re-retrieve the desired result.

Picture the following EditorTemplate for a `CustomerId` property on your model:

```
@model Int32
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x, new SelectList(
  Customers.GetAllCustomers().Select(y => new SelectListItem {
    Value = y.Id,
    Text = y.Name,
    Selected = Model == y.Id
  })
);
```

And of course:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.CustomerId) @* Use above EditorTemplate *@
```

Then in your submit action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult(MyViewModel model)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    // ID was passed, re-fetch the customer based on selected id
    Customer customer = Customers.GetById(model.CustomerId)
    /* ... */
  }
  /* ... */
  return View();
}
```